Why I am getting context_recall value of 0 with RAGAs framework and "TypeError(ufunc 'invert' error?
When using the RAGAs framework to evaluate my RAG solution, I am getting the following error. I don't think the Pandas framework has error as all source Excel file values could be read without error (checked with print statements).

TypeError(ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'')

I am also getting a context recall value of 0. I am unable to figure out why this happens. Can someone help?
I posted it in their GitHub page but no one responded yet.
